# How to find out where VMware and its virtual machines are installed?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, vmware

I have installed VMware and Virtual Windows 10 in Ubuntu 22.04.

I installed VMware by downloading the file from [VMware download page](https://www.vmware.com/fi/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) and installing it.

I installed my Virtual Windows 10 by downloading the file from [Windows 10 Virtual machine download page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) and installing (openning) it in the virtual machine.

Is there any way to find out which packages VMware and Windows10 include and where those packages are installed in my Ubuntu 22.04 machine?

TIA

Comment: Who "they" are you asking about? Are you asking about Windows 10 packages?

Comment: I meant both VMware packages and its virtual machine or machines packages (if they need any), so in this case Windows 10.

Comment: How exactly did you install VMware and Virtual Windows 10? I suggest to add links to the source of these software packages. Please [edit] your question to provide requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation in the [pdf file](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Linux/16.0/workstation-player-16-linux-user-guide.pdf) page 92, there is a good chance that the directory */usr/lib/vmware* is where these files are stored.